# Comparing two text files and save the missing

Tags: command-line, text, diff

I have two text files:

first text file:

```
Hello
Hi
Hola
Bonjour
```

Second text file:

```
Hi 
Bonjour
```

How can I output the differences between them regardless the line number i.e. I want to save the output which is

```
Hello
Hola
```

Into a new text file

Comment: It depends what you mean by "differences between them" - lines that are in the first but not in the second? in the second but not in the first? both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk command can solve this problem:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{uu[$1]=1}NR!=FNR&&uu[$1]!=1{print}' second first
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what "the differences" means, but here is something that meets your given inputs and output:

```
$ cat >1
Hello
Hi
Hola
Bonjour

$ cat >2
Hi
Bonjour

$ diff  --old-line-format=''  <(sort 1)  <(sort 2)  >new

$ cat new
Hi
Bonjour
```

Comment: Thanks, I mean by differences: words exists in the first file and does not exist in the second one.

Answer (score 1):

To output whole lines that exist in the first file but not in the second:

```
grep -vxFf second first
```

Alternatively, sort the files and then use `comm`:

```
comm -23 <(sort first) <(sort second)
```

Comment: Feel free to add my "diff" method (do the "<sort" too) to your answer and delete mine.

Comment: @RayButterworth `diff` doesn't seem to fit the OP's requirement to show differences "regardless the line number"