# How can I diff two files, deleting lines in file1 from file2

Tags: command-line, text-processing, diff

I want to take file1 and remove all the lines that are contained in file2, ideally keeping the filename file1 once done, keeping the unmodified lines of anything remaining.

I've tried using diff as follows

```
diff --suppress-common-lines file1 file2 > newfile
```

This gives me either and output `<` or `>` at the start of each line depending on the order of the two files, which I don't want.

Also tried using comm:

```
comm -23 file1 file2 > newfile
```

this requires line to be re-ordered, and the lines I have are all order sensitive.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: It *sounds* like you want something like `grep -vxFf file2 file1` or `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} !($0 in a)' file2 file1` - see for example [Comparing two text files and save the missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153850/comparing-two-text-files-and-save-the-missing)

Comment: @steeldriver make that an answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  This work for the most part, the files are an comparing are network switch configurations, which use the ! character between sections.  Both these solutions remove these characters, and I would like to keep them.
is there a way to keep those characters?

Comment: @wavers please [edit] your question with a minimal example of the 2 files and your desired output. Or delete this question and ask a more specific one - as it stands, it's a duplicate of the one I linked.

Comment: Never mind, my base fil included the !, took those out and all is good.
Thanks